# How to Combine Two Tables Into One Beautiful Soup Object

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am querying a website and scraping data from the table(s) on the resulting page. Sometimes there is more than one table (I don't know beforehand). The HTML code looks something like this:

```
<div id="containter1" class="rank-container"
    <table class="ysr-list" id="ysr-list1">
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="name1"></tr>
            <tr class="name2"></tr>
            <tr class="name3"></tr>
        </tbody>
```

and sometimes it looks like this

```
<div id="containter1" class="rank-container"
    <table class="ysr-list" id="ysr-list1">
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="name1"></tr>
            <tr class="name2"></tr>
            <tr class="name3"></tr>
        </tbody>

bla bla bla

<div id="containter2" class="rank-container"
    <table class="ysr-list" id="ysr-list2">
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="name1"></tr>
            <tr class="name2"></tr>
            <tr class="name3"></tr>
        </tbody>
```

What I am currently doing is

```
Table = soup.find('table', {'id':'ysr-list1'})
```

however, this obviously misses the second table when there is one.  What I would like to do is somehow combine the tables into one BS object

```
Table1 = soup.find('table', {'id':'ysr-list1'})
Table2 = soup.find('table', {'id':'ysr-list2'})

Table = Table1 + Table2
```

where `Table` is of type `bs4.element.Tag` (which is the type of `Table1` and `Table2`) so I can grab all the rows of all the tables on a given page by

```
TableRows = Table.find_all('tr')
```

I would also like an elegant suggestion on the best way to automatically determine how many tables are present that have `id=ysr-listX` where `X` is the number of tables on the page and gather them all into a `bs4.element.Tag` object as described above.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You could use [lxml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.2.4) in combination with [cssselect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cssselect) and then use CSS Selector
semantics to search for the two tables by their class name returning a list of elements.

Here's an example:

```
>>> html = open("test.html", "r").read()
>>> from lxml.html import fromstring
>>> import cssselect
>>> doc = fromstring(html)
>>> doc.cssselect("table.ysr-list")
[<Element table at 0x1044606b0>, <Element table at 0x104460710>]
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using list comprehension and `findAll` to find

- a list of all `table` objects in the soup
- a list of `tr` in the list of table objects

Here's the code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs

input = '''<html><head><title>title</title></head>
<body>
<p>paragraph</p>
<div><div>
    <table>table1<table>inner11<table>inner12</table></table></table>
    <div><table>table2<table>inner2</table></table></div>
</div></div>
<table>table3<table>inner3</table></table>
<table>table4<table>inner4</table></table>
</html>'''
input = '''
<div id="containter1" class="rank-container"
    <table class="ysr-list" id="ysr-list1">
            <thead></thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr class="name1"></tr>
            <tr class="name2"></tr>
            <tr class="name3"></tr>
         </tbody>
    </table>

bla bla bla

<div id="containter2" class="rank-container"
    <table class="ysr-list" id="ysr-list2">
            <thead></thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr class="name1"></tr>
            <tr class="name2"></tr>
            <tr class="name3"></tr>
         </tbody>
    </table>

<div id="containter3" class="rank-container"
    <table class="ysr-list" id="ysr-list1">
            <thead></thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr class="name4"></tr>
            <tr class="name5"></tr>
            <tr class="name6"></tr>
         </tbody>
    </table>
'''
soup = bs(input)
alltables = soup.findAll("table",{'id':'ysr-list1'})
print "Number of ysr-list1 tables found : " , len(alltables)

allrows=[table.findAll('tr') for table in alltables]

allrows=[row for sublist in allrows for row in sublist]
for row in allrows:
 print row
```

And the output with Python 2.7:

```
Number of ysr-list1 tables found :  2
<tr class="name1"></tr>
<tr class="name2"></tr>
<tr class="name3"></tr>
<tr class="name4"></tr>
<tr class="name5"></tr>
<tr class="name6"></tr>
```

Comment: this appears to be unfinished

Comment: Really sorry, my browser doesn't show scroll bars on these code fields so I only saw the top half of your answer and it looked like that's all there was.  My bad.